# The A-PDF Watermark application is applying a 'Not Registered' watermark even though it is

Tags: pdf, watermark

I have downloaded and registered the [a-pdf watermark](http://www.a-pdf.com/watermark/) software that watermarks pdf files. I have recently moved server and I have registered the software. When i run it via the GUI it correctly creates the watermarks.

However when I do it via my PHP application I get an extra watermark saying I haven't registered the software, but I have.

How can I get rid of this watermark?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the software only registers itself for the current user.  My php application runs as `nt authority\system` which doesnt have the reg code entered in its section of the registry.

### To Fix

Copy the RegisterCode value from

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\A-PDF\Watermark\Register
```

key to

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\A-PDF\Watermark\Register
```

and then it works fine without the unregistered watermark.